# How to create a Symfony2.1 Validation Constraint to validate the number of tokens in a string

Tags: validation, symfony, token, symfony-2.1

Sometimes happen that a collection of values is stored in a database as a unique string. This string is so made of all the values separated by a user-defined delimiter (e.g. "," or "_").

What would be nice in a Symfony2.1 application is to have a Validation Constraint that validates a string (e.g. provided by an input text form) by counting the number of tokens included in that string.

A possible example is when you store the tags in a string format, i.e. you receive a string from an input field like `value1,value2,value10,value25`. You see that 4 tokens are passed, but there is no form validator that does that control for you. So, one should use such a validator like:

```
/**
* @Assert\Token(
     *      delimiter=",", 
     *      min = "1",
     *      max = "5",
     *      minMessage = "You must specify at least one token",
     *      maxMessage = "You cannot specify more than 5 tokens")
*/ 
$tags;
```

There is something similar when using the **new in Symfony2.1** [Count](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Count.html) validator, but is doesn't work on strings, just on array of objects that implements Countable.

Who know how to implement that kind of "tokenized string" validator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, I just want to share my solutions.

One possible solution is to use a [Callback constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html). For instance, following the tag list example provided in the question:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"isTagStringValid"})
 */
class AFormModel{

protected $tags;

    public function isTagStringValid(ExecutionContext $context){
        $tagsExploded = explode(',', $this->tags);

        if(count($tagsExploded)==0){
            $context->addViolationAtSubPath('tags', 'Insert at least a tag', array(), null);    
        }
        if(count($tagsExploded)==1 && $tagsExploded[0]==='')
            $context->addViolationAtSubPath('tags', 'Insert at least a tag', array(), null);            
        }
        else if(count($tagsExploded)>10){
            $context->addViolationAtSubPath('tags', 'Max 10 values', array(), null);            
        }
    }

}
```

---

A more elegant way is to define the "Token" validator. An example follows here:

```
namespace .....

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
  * @Annotation
*/
class Token extends Constraint {
    public $min;
    public $max;
    public $minMessage = '{{ min }} token(s) are expected';
    public $maxMessage = '{{ max }} token(s) are expected';
    public $invalidMessage = 'This value should be a string.';   
    public $delimiter = ',';
public function __construct($options = null){
    parent::__construct($options);

    if (null === $this->min && null === $this->max) {
        throw new MissingOptionsException('Either option "min" or "max" must be given for constraint ' . __CLASS__, array('min', 'max'));
    }
}
```

}

And the validator class is:

```
namespace ...

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class TokenValidator extends ConstraintValidator {
    public function isValid($value, Constraint $constraint) {
        if ($value === null) {
            return;
        }
        if(!is_string($value)){
            $this->context->addViolation($constraint->invalidMessage, array(
                '{{ value }}' => $value,
            ));

            return;
        }

        $tokensExploded = explode($constraint->delimiter, $value);
        $tokens = count($tokensExploded);
        if($tokens==1){
            if($tokensExploded[0]==='')
                $tokens = 0;
        }

        if (null !== $constraint->max && $tokens > $constraint->max) {
            $this->context->addViolation($constraint->maxMessage, array(
                '{{ value }}' => $value,
                '{{ limit }}' => $constraint->max,
            ));

            return;
        }
        if (null !== $constraint->min && $tokens < $constraint->min) {
            $this->context->addViolation($constraint->minMessage, array(
                '{{ value }}' => $value,
                '{{ limit }}' => $constraint->min,
            ));
        }        
    }
}
```

In this way you can import the user-defined validator and use it everywhere like I proposed in my question.